# Update number in same place on web page with javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, delay

Is there a way to make JavaScript print a counter continuously in the same place on the page?

```
for(var x=0; x<3000; x++){
    document.write(x + '</br>');
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
}
```

I want the number x to update and replace the previous number, however this code seems to wait until the loop is finished before showing a number (by then it is too late)

Is there a way to say, print number x, now wait 100ms, now clear and update in the same space the new value for x, and repeat?

(I know that the `innerHTML` is killing the whole page, for now all this pages needs to do is run a counter, so other elements are irrelevant. What I don't want is a printed list of all those numbers, and I need a delay)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser will not update the display while JavaScript is running. To make a timer happen you need to use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`. Also, avoid `document.write()` unless you have a good reason to use it (if you're not sure what makes a good reason then don't use it at all).

You want something like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="counter"></div>
</body>
```

Then:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var x = 0,
        max = 3000,
        ctr = document.getElementById("counter");

    function incrementCounter() {
       ctr.innerHTML = x;
       if (x++ < max)
           setTimeout(incrementCounter, 100);
    }

    incrementCounter();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/v5hmE/

Note that the above updates only the contents of the "counter" div, so any other elements on your page would not be affected.

Homework assignment for you: Google everything you didn't understand in that code.

Comment: You're welcome. I assigned homework because (a) it was a cop-out to avoid explaining everything in detail, but also because (b) I got the impression you genuinely want to learn and would therefore benefit from finding stuff out for yourself. A tip: when googling JavaScript stuff add " mdn" to your search, e.g., "settimeout mdn" - the first result is usually a page from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript), a really good JS resource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! For that purpose I would recommend you two things:

1. To use a container (lets say a div) for that purpose:

   and refer to it as `document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = x`
2. To use [javascript timers](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CE8QFjAA&url=http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp&ei=LzEjULzLEMuaiAfs0YHYBQ&usg=AFQjCNFkWK5XLaslzcd5uM3rUtr3fyjP0Q) before updating.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hey Ramon, how do I populate that div? Because JavaScript runs before its populated (even if I put in some paragraphs) and returns a error thats its Null (If I run this in Chromes console after its loaded it works, but not when the page runs)

Comment: Hi @Joseph, there comes another story. You will find many situations in which you would like to execute javascript code after the page finishes loading. That's why I would recommend you to take a look at one of the best Javascript libraries ever created: jQuery. Apart from that functionality, it will also save you from issues as cross browser compatibility, and will keep you apart from reinventing the wheel(as there are plenty of helpful plugins for jQuery - i.e. jQueryUI).

Answer (score 1):

> *...however this code seems to wait until the loop is finished before showing a number...*

Don't use a `for` loop for this. You need a specific interval like you say. Use a function with a `setTimeout` and some recursion:

```
var x = 0;
var speed = 100;
function update() {
  if (x <= 3000) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // update DOM here
      x++; 
      update();
    }, speed);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/PRC9R/

You can change the interval to say `9` so it looks believable but goes faster.

```
x += 9; // instead of x++
```